# what is the # symbol in the url

Tags: html

I went to some photo sharing site, so when I click the photo, it direct me to a url like

`www.example.com/photoshare.php?photoid=1234445`

. and when I click the other photo in this page the url become

`www.example.com/photoshare.php?photoid=1234445#3338901`

and if I click other photos in the same page, the only the number behind # changes. Same as the pretty photo like

`www.example.com/photoshare.php?album=holiday#!prettyPhoto[gallery2]/2/`

.I assume they used ajax because the whole page seems not loaded, but the url is changed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The portion of a URL (including and) following the `#` is the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It is special from the rest of the URL. The key to remember is "client-side only" (of course, a client could choose to send it to the server ... just not as a fragment identifier):

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, **its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the server** — of course the server typically helps to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a resource from a Web server, **the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment.** Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then **the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.**

This can be used to navigate to "anchor" links, like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics (note how it goes the "Basics" section).

While this used to just go to "anchors" in the past, it is now used to store navigatable state in many JavaScript-powered sites -- gmail makes heavy use of it, for instance. And, as is the case here, there is some "photoshare" JavaScript that also makes use of the fragment identifier for state/navigation.

Thus, as suspected, the JavaScript "captures" the fragment (sometimes called "hash") changing and performs AJAX (or other background task) to update the page. The page itself is not reloaded when the fragment changes because the URL still refers to the *same* server resource (the part of the URL before the fragment identifier).

Newer browsers support the `onhashchange` event but monitoring has been supported for a long time by various polling techniques.

Happy coding.

Comment: @smith [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) -- where onhashchange is supported ;-) Otherwise, refer to the source of a "cross browser" implementation, such as [jQuery hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Comment: @smith `#` is the first character of the fragment identifier. The `#` **and everything after** is part of the fragment identifier. Google uses a crawling method that *utilizes* certain fragments that start with `#!` -- this is their convention/approach (and everyone who wants a well/correctly-indexed "interactive" site is apt to follow it, google being "the big dog".) See the link in Chuck's answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's called the fragment identifier. It identifies a "part" of the page. If there is an element with a `name` or `id` attribute equal to the fragment text, it will cause the page to scroll to that element. They're also used by rich JavaScript apps to refer to different parts of the app even though all the functionality is located on a single HTML page.

Lately, you'll often see fragments that start with "#!". Although these are still technically just fragments that start with the <kbd>!</kbd> character, that format was [specified by Google](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) to help make these AJAXy pseudo-pages crawlable.

Comment: so #! is the same as and #? can you show me how javascript work with it,  like they did for the photo? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The '#' symbol in the context of a url (and other things) is called a hash, what comes after the hash is called a fragment. Using JavaScript you can access the fragment and use its contents.

For example most browsers implement a `onhashchange` event, which fires when the hash changes.    Using JavaScript you can also access the hash from `location.hash`. For example, with a url like `http://something.com#somethingelse`

```
var frag = location.hash.substr(1);
console.log(frag);
```

This would print 'somethingelse' to the console. If we didn't use `substr` to remove the first character, it `frag` would be: '#somethingelse'.

Also, when you navigate to a URL with a hashtag, the browser will try and scroll down to an element which has an `id` corresponding to the fragment.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: What you call a "hashtag" is properly called a "fragment".

Comment: so how to use javascript to access tp the fragement, could you show me an example,

Answer (score 2):

It is the name attribute of an anchor URL: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp

It is used to make a bookmark **within** an HTML page (and not to be confused with bookmarks in toolbars, etc.).

In your example, if you bookmarked the page with the # symbol in the URL, when you visit that bookmark again it will display the last image that you viewed, most likely an image that has the id of 3338901.

Answer (score 1):

hey i used sumthing like this .... simple but useful

```
       location.href = data.url.replace(/%2523/, '%23');
```

where data.url is my original url . It substitutes the # in my url