# HttpContext.Current.Request with Angular ui-router

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Using Asp.Net I am capturing the request of an `AngularJS` Route as it loads. The route is  `/FST/#/quickstart`. I am trying to capture that route with:

```
var currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
```

however, the `RawUrl` doesn't contain the `#/quickstart` subpart. There doesn't seem to be any thing in the Request than can tell me the full URL. How can I get the target URL?

Comment: You cannot pass `#` in a URL to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the # symbol in the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909969/what-is-the-symbol-in-the-url)

Comment: There is no point in getting the hash part on server side when we develop with angularJs. The hash `should be used to do routing` on client side which may send parsed parameters (if any) to server side.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a `$http` interceptor to add the current route as a header to your web api request

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q','$location' function($q, $location) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                config.headers.ClientSideUrl = $location.path();
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },
            'requestError': function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            'response': function(response) {
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };

    }]);
```

And then access the header server side:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("ClientSideUrl").FirstOrDefault();`