# Get the value of variables passed in the url

Tags: python, django, url, post, get

Hi I am using Mandrill to send few emails from my system(Mandrill is designed to help applications or websites that need to send transactional email like password resets, order confirmations, and welcome messages.) I am preparing a url and attaching it to emails.When user clicks on the link in these emails he will be redirected to a particular section in a web page.

The url I have attached is something like this : "https://mysite/account/subs/#manage_contacts"

If user is logged into my application,He ll be redirected to the specific url,If not he is redirected to login page with the site and target variables set to redirect him to the url he clicked.

In the login page this is the url :

"https://mysite/authenticate/?site=xyz&target=/account/subs/#manage_contacts"

But after login the user is redirected to 'mysite/account/subs/'.
leaving out "#manage_contacts".How do I get the entire url in the target.
I checked the value of target, It had only mysite/account/subs/

A part of views which is responsible for redirection after successful login :

```
  
        site = request.GET.get('site', '')
        logger.debug('site:' + str(site))
        target = request.GET.get('target', '')
        logger.debug('target:' + str(target))
        if site and target:
            redirect_url = target
        else:
            redirect_url = '/authenticate/'
        logger.debug('redirect_url:' + str(redirect_url))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is a mark for browser to display more friendly.

It's not a part of the http request, so you can't get the `#manage_contacts` through

```
target = request.GET.get('target', '')
```

For detail info:

[what-is-the-symbol-in-the-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909969/what-is-the-symbol-in-the-url)

[Fragment_identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the #. The browser is treating this as a fragment for the current URL, and those don't get sent to the backend.

Set the target URL instead to `https://mysite/account/subs/%23manage_contacts`.