# How do I prevent direct accessing of the view servlet while using angular?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, servlets

I've got a little problem with access java servlets. I returned to servlet list of records from my database and it should`t be able to view by normal user.

I`ve got something like this :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CandidateAdd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.recrutationapp.servlets.CandidateServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CandidateAdd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CandidateAddServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In html I'm using angular services to access to this servlet via POST :

```
$http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/RecrutationApp_ver_1.1-1.1/CandidateAddServlet",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: $scope.candidateToSend
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.status = data;
            $window.alert("Candidate Added!");
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
        }).error(function () {
            $window.alert("Error!!");
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
        });
```

This works fine but when I type an URL like : localhost:8080/ProjectName/CandidateAddServlet it shows all the data sends by servlet...

When I'm trying something like this :

```
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>CandidateAdd</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/#/CandidateAddServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And :

```
method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/RecrutationApp_ver_1.1-1.1/#/CandidateAddServlet",
```

It not works and I cant find solutions to this problem...

I don't use .jsp files. I'm writing every single web page in html files.

Comment: You cannot use the # in server-side URL as this symbol is called fragment identifier and is intended for client-side processing.
See this discussion for more detailed explanation: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909969/what-is-the-symbol-in-the-url

Comment: Why exactly is it a problem if the enduser can call the same servlet as the webpage itself is using to get the data which it ultimately presents to the very same enduser?

Comment: It's problem because when user enters for example : /#/candidateAdd sites he will see the normal html site, but when he types in url /candidateAddServlet he will see JSON with data from database. I want to disable this but I don't know how...