# Meaning of the symbol "!" inside URL when using ui-route angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm a newbie in js, I follow this [example](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight) to study how to route UI in SPA with angularjs. 

When I download and run this example, the URL is

```
"http://localhost:8080/#/home"
```

but when I start to create my sample myself, the URL always is

```
"http://localhost:8080/#!/home"
```

I don't know the meaning of **"!"** symbol in the URL. My sample still work but the "!" inside the URL make me confuse, I wonder that "something was missing, isn't it?"
Please teach me or give me some keywords to understand the problem deeper.
Thanks

Comment: it's called hashbang mode (`#`-hash, `!`-bang).  it's documented and discussed in detail in the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the # symbol in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909969/what-is-the-symbol-in-the-url)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: With AngularJS V1.6, the default hash-prefix used for `$location` hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string `('')` to the bang `('!')`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-location-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is called [**Fragment_identifier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

---

The `$location` service is designed to support hash prefixed URLs
for cases where the browser does not support HTML5 push-state navigation.

The Google Ajax Crawling Scheme expects that local paths within a SPA start
with a hash-bang (e.g. `somedomain.com/base/path/#!/client/side/path`).

The `$locationProvide` allows the application developer to configure the
hashPrefix, and it is normal to set this to a bang '!', but the default
has always been the empty string ''.

This has caused some confusion where a user is not aware of this feature
and wonders why adding a hash value to the location (e.g. `$location.hash('xxx')`)
results in a double hash: `##xxx`.

This commit changes the default value of the prefix to '!', which is more
natural and expected.

See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

[Referred from](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52)

and please visit here : [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, and reference. Now I understand the symbol's meaning. I will spend more time in $locationProvider and $location too. btw, a small question (I think it relates to my op), as you said "The $locationProvide allows the application developer to configure the hashPrefix, and it is normal to set this to a bang '!', but the default has always been the empty string ''. 
I don't know the use case of config the hashPrefix, atm I think that we can use the default hashbang instead of config it to hash, can you give me some hint?

Comment: With AngularJS V1.6, the default hash-prefix used for `$location` hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string `('')` to the bang `('!')`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#-location-).