# IIS Rewrite hash(#) in url

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am working in an application that is using .NET as backend and ReactJS as frontend framework. Currently, we want to migrate from React Hash Router to React Browser Router. The change has gone well. The only problem we face is that we are not able to write a successfull IIS rewrite rule redirecte the urls with "#" to urls without hash.

Is there any way using IIS redirect to change:
https://sampleApp/#/category/3/id/45255
into:
https://sampleApp/category/3/id/45255

We have tried with that rule and some varitions.

```
<rule name="HashRemoval" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)#(.*)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Please break it down to smaller questions and study: 1) why there are `#`s in URLs and 2) why browsers take care of them, not web servers like IIS. Then you should know the answer.

Comment: Hi @LexLi the "#" appears from nothing appart from React Hash Router (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909969/what-is-the-symbol-in-the-url Sounds like people forgot about the actual meaning after so many years.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS , the URL Rewrite module does not natively handle the anchor part of the URL because this part is handled on the client side and is not sent to the server as part of the HTTP request. request will not reach to the server so IIS URL Rewrite rules can't match against it, as it is never seen in the incoming request on the server side.

so it would be batter if you perform the redirection at client side.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  const newLocation = window.location.href.replace(/#/, '');
  window.location.replace(newLocation);
}
```

Here is the iis url rewrite router rule:

```
<rule name="ReactAppRoutes" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
</rule>
```